# How to fill checkboxes given a start and number of checkboxes to fill?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been thinking for a efficient solution for this, but i can't find a way, i have 8 checkboxes in a groupbox, and i want to check some of them given a start checkbox and the number of subsequent checkbox to fill.

```
public void modifyDigitalPins(byte adress, byte lenght)
{
    int startPin = (byte)adress;
    int numberPins = (byte)lenght;

    foreach(CheckBox a in groupBox2.Controls)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "subsequent" implies an ordering.  Where does that ordering come from?

Comment: the method receives two bytes, one for the start checkbox, and the other for number of checkbox to fill, let mee put the complete code for the method.

Comment: I would put the controls in an array so I could be *certain* of the order, then just iterate it

Comment: Use a CheckedListBox control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are called "checkBox1" through "checkBox8", you could do something like:

```
public void modifyDigitalPins(byte address, byte length)
{
    int startPin = (byte)address;
    int numberPins = (byte)length;

    for(int i=1; i <= numberPins; i++)
    {
        Control ctl = this.Controls.Find("checkBox" + (startPin + (i - 1)).ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ctl != null && ctl is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)ctl;
            cb.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be easily modified if your controls follow a different naming scheme.

Comment: Many thanks this works, i tried with the checklistbox but i couldn't find the right way, but this solution works!